# Relation is not removed when calling unsetRelation()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen, laravel-collection

`unsetRelation('relation')` is not removed when calling `pluck('relation')`

```php
$data = Model::with([
        'child', 'child.one', 'child.two'
])->get()
```

**Removes 'child.one' and 'child.two' but keeps child**

```php
$data->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    if($key == 1){ //remove the second item
              $item->unsetRelation('child'); //same behavior if we call $item->unsetRelations();  
        }
        return $item;
});

$output = $data->pluck('child');
```

After calling pluck if we had 2 items under `$data->child`, the first contains all 3 relations ( `child`, `child.one`, `child.two`), the second item contains only `child`. I guess if we call `unsetRelation` should not return it after `pluck` method?

If we call `dd($data)` after `transform` relation is not there.

**Update**

```php
$items = Model::with([
    'child',
    'child.one',
    'child.two'
])->get();

$items->transform(function($item, $key) use ($request){

    if($this->filter($item->child, $request)){ //check if need to exclude

        $item->child->param_1 = $item->id; //as example there is more logic

    }else{

        $item->unsetRelation('child');

    }

    return $item;

});

return $items->pluck('child');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a pluck on an attribute that is a relation, it will be loaded if the relation is not already present.

For your example, you can `$data = Model::get()` then `$data->pluck('child')`; you will get the child of each one and not an empty collection.

To remove a relation specifically for a collection pluck, set the relation as empty

```php
$data->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    if($key == 1){ //remove the second item
          $item->setRelation('child', collect([]);
    }
    return $item;
});
```

This will make the relation marked as loaded and still returning and empty result.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I need to remove a `child` relation based on few criteria, I can run `filter` and after run 'transform' this will do the trick, but wanted to do it one loop.

Comment: You need to remove the relation in the database ? or just in the results ? can you add your complete code in your question ?

Comment: @Froxz i dont see the issue with the solution i proposed. just replace `unsetRelation('child')` with `setRelation('child', collect([])`

Comment: this creates empty collections, after calling `pluck` they still exists.

Comment: What kind of result do you expect ? if you pluck  X elements you will get X results.